# Tangling knitr files that use an external code file

Tags: r, knitr, coderef

Is there a way to include the externaL code in the tangled file when I have:

```
<<xref>>=
@
```

(here xref is a reference to code in an external file)

or

```
<<internal-ref>>=
<<xref>>
@
```

Or do I need to source the external file and somehow work from that?

This is an issue when including knitr vignettes in packages.  At the final stage of
checking on a vignette, R tries to source the tangled file.  Missing code causes
problems!

I am using version 1.5 of knitr.

Answer (score 1):

The original design of `purl()` is flawed in many aspects. For example, it does not respect cross references using `<<>>`. I really do not think `R CMD build/check` should tangle the vignettes at all, since weaving has run the code once. That said, you can try the [latest development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/), in which I introduced a new function `hook_purl()` that should serve much better as the tangling utility. To enable it, use

```
knit_hooks$set(purl = hook_purl)
```

Then tangling is done during weaving time, which means whatever is executed is written to the R script. This guarantees the tangled R script really contains the code executed. You only need to call `knit()` once to get both the output document and the R script.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using **knitr** version 1.5, and the second option you offered works fine for me.

Here, the only R code in the document is stored in a named unevaluated chunk in `"child.Rnw"`:

```
<<xref, eval=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results="hide">>=
d <- 1:10
d
@
```

That file and its chunk are read into the main file, `"main.Rnw"`, by an initial chunk that uses the `child="filename"` option. A second chunk evaluates the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<child, child="child.Rnw", eval=TRUE>>=
@

<<internal-ref, eval=TRUE>>=
<<xref>>
@

\end{document}
```

It knits just fine, and more importantly, doing `purl("main.Rnw")` produces a tangled file `"main.R"` that includes all of the R code. `"main.R"` looks like this:

```
## ----child, child="child.Rnw", eval=TRUE---------------------------------

## ----xref, eval=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results="hide"------------------------
## d <- 1:10
## d


## ----internal-ref, eval=TRUE---------------------------------------------
d <- 1:10
d
```

I haven't tried running this as a vignette, but since it's not missing any of the source code, it looks it should at least solve your proximal problem...